# Extjs 4.1 (rc2) - Extension on Ext.panel.Panel sometimes does not finish rendering

Tags: javascript, extjs, rendering

I have a class extending on Ext.panel.Panel.

Simplified code:

```
Ext.define("some.namespace.MyOwnPanel", { 
    extends: "Ext.panel.Panel",

    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;

        Ext.apply(this, config);
        this.callParent(arguments);

        this.layout = "border";

        this.centerPanel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel" , {
            region: "center",
            layout: "fit",
            border: false
        });

        this.westPanel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel", {
            region: "west",
            layout: "fit",
            border: false
        });

        this.add(this.centerPanel);
        this.add(this.westPanel);

        this.on("afterrender", function () {
            // create grid for center panel. Data is loaded with AJAX in that function and the component is also added to this.centerPanel
            me.createGrid();
        });
    }
}
```

sometimes it works and the afterrender event is fired, but sometimes it doesn't work and then the web application crashes. No error is given, but any creation of ext components stops beyond that point.

I have tried many things. The original code, which is mostly written by a co-worker, has more traces of Extjs 3.1 code that is compatible in 4.1. I tried rewriting it to proper 4.1 code but to no success. I tried to move the code to the initComponent method but also that failed.

I have no more ideas about how to fix this. Has anyone encountered such a thing before, and what did you do? Please tell me!

Comment: The most suspicious line to me is `Ext.apply(this, config);` Add a console.log before it and make sure you're passing in the correct input. It has the potential to replace the properties of this class instance.

Comment: I checked the config with the console.log, but that only has specific properties for above class; no important Ext.panel.Panel properties are overwritten

Answer (score 1):

I think you need create this.centerPanel = Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel" , { ...
in initComponent() function:

```
initComponent: function() {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        centerPanel: Ext.create("Ext.panel.Panel" , { ... },
        ...
    });
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

Not in constructor.

Comment: Also see: you write - extends: "Ext.panel.Panel", not "extend".

Comment: I followed up your answer, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has to do with doing the class set up in the `constructor` and not the `initComponent`.  `initComponent` is the recommended way to set up the class, the constructor should only be overridden for special cases.  The way the class is set up the `afterrender` event may not fire if your class is created with the `renderTo` config which would explain the sometimes working and failing.

```
Ext.define('Bad', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    constructor: function() {
        //the parent constructor is called here and if renderTo 
        // is defined it will render before the afterrender listener is added
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.on('afterrender', function(){
            window.alert('rendered')
        })
    }
})

var works = new Bad();
//this will alert rendered
works.render(document.body)

//this wont
new Bad({renderTo: document.body})

Ext.define('Good', {
    extend: 'Ext.Component',
    //change constructor to initComponent
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.on('afterrender', function(){
            window.alert('rendered')
        })
    }
})

//alerts 
new Good({renderTo: document.body})
```

Comment: I followed up your answer, but unfortunately it did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: @DanielvanDommele without the actual code, it is going to be hard to pinpoint the problem.  When something goes wrong and doesn't "error" I  normally check the break on all errors in firebug (pause on exceptions in chrome) reproduce the error and investigate the stack trace.